# Inverse to cbind() function R

Tags: r, matrix, cbind

Suppose I have a list of matrices:

```
matrix <- matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
list <- list(matrix, matrix, matrix)
```

And a matrix created by function `cbind()`:

```
long.matrix <- do.call(cbind, list)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    3    1    3    1    3
[2,]    2    4    2    4    2    4
```

I want to reverse the process to get `list` of matrices from the `long.matrix`.

I can do it manually with the `for` loop, but I am searching for something like: `function(long.matrix, 3)` which I think should exist. Is there a such thing?

Comment: Very close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145863/splitting-a-dataframe-into-equal-parts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brute-force solution:

```
f <- function(long.matrix, num)
           lapply(split(long.matrix, 
                        rep(seq(num), each=(ncol(long.matrix)/num)*nrow(long.matrix))), 
                  function(x) matrix(x, nrow=nrow(long.matrix))
           )

f(long.matrix, 3)
## $`1`
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    3
## [2,]    2    4
## 
## $`2`
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    3
## [2,]    2    4
## 
## $`3`
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    3
## [2,]    2    4
```

`rep` builds the categories for `split`, to split the data.  As R is column-major, here we take the first four, second four, an third four entries.

Filling in the values for the current dimensions of your example `long.matrix` and `3`, the function reduces to this:

```
lapply(split(long.matrix, rep(seq(3), each=4)), function(x) matrix(x, nrow=2))
```

Note:

```
(r <- rep(seq(3), each=4) )
## [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
split(long.matrix, r)
## $`1`
## [1] 1 2 3 4
## 
## $`2`
## [1] 1 2 3 4
## 
## $`3`
## [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Each of those is then passed to `matrix` to get the desired format.

Comment: Thank you! I get it more or less :) You think there is no such thing implemented in base R?

Comment: @cure I do not think that there is, but I would love to be shown to be incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! The anwer seems complete. That would be the reason i could not find straightforward solution. Should I edit question, that it probably does not exist and needs to be done manually?

Comment: @cure I don't think that it is necessary.  When asking for a solution, a built-in or a solution in a package is (almost) always preferred, but code to do the work is generally acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
listm=list()  #i=1
for(i in 1:3)listm[[i]]=long.matrix[,(2*i-1):(i*2)]
```

The lapply version

```
lapply(1:3,function(ii)long.matrix[,(2*ii-1):(ii*2)])

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using array dimensions for this. You can then define a `split` method for matrices:

```
split.matrix <- function(x, rslice = 1, cslice = 1) {
  if (ncol(x) %% cslice) stop("cslice not divisor of number of columns")
  if (nrow(x) %% rslice) stop("rslice not divisor of number of rows")

  x <- t(x)
  dim(x) <- c(dim(x)[1],
              dim(x)[2] / rslice,
              rslice)
  x <- lapply(seq_len(rslice), function(k, a) t(a[,,k]), a = x)

  if (cslice > 1) {
    x <- lapply(x, function(y, k) {

      dim(y) <- c(dim(y)[1],
                  dim(y)[2] / k,
                  k)
      y <- lapply(seq_len(k), function(k, a) a[,,k], a = y)
      y
    }, k = cslice)
  }
  if(length(x) == 1L) x <- x[[1]]

  x
}

split(long.matrix, 1, 3)
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
#
#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
#
#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4

split(long.matrix, 1, 1)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    3    1    3    1    3
#[2,]    2    4    2    4    2    4

split(long.matrix, 2, 1)

#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    3    1    3    1    3
#
#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    2    4    2    4    2    4

split(long.matrix, 2, 3)
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1 3
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 1 3
#
#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] 1 3
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 2 4
#
#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 2 4
#
#[[2]][[3]]
#[1] 2 4
```