# Is there a way to slice a tibble

Tags: r, loops, slice

I want to create new tibbles (or dataframes) from a large dataset. I want to do this by slicing every x rows.

Example data:

```
library(dplyr)

iris2 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(ID = seq.int(nrow(iris)))
iris2 <- as_tibble(iris2)

iris_1_10 <- iris2 %>% slice(1:10)
iris_11_20 <- iris2 %>% slice(11:20)
```

I could do this for for the whole dataset, but is there a better way? This is just a demo using `iris` but my dataset is a lot bigger.

I have tried to write a `loop` and to use `apply` but I am not very good at that yet.

I am wondering if someone with more knowledge of this could help me do this in a more efficient way.

Comment: See `?split` and this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145863/splitting-a-data-frame-into-equal-parts

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help.