# Splitting a data.frame into N parts of approximately equal length in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

Consider the following dataset, where:

- X*n* values are rib length measurements for ten lizard species (A-J). `X1`
  is the length of the first rib, `X2` is the length of the second rib,
  and so on.
- Y*n* values are between-rib space lengths for the same lizards. `Y1` is
  the length of the space between the first and second ribs, `Y2` is the
  length of the space between the second and third ribs, and so on.
- The variable `n.ribs` is the number of ribs of each lizard. Note that
  the lizards have different numbers of ribs, ranging from 7 to 20.
- The variable `total.length` is the total length of the ribcage of
  each lizard.
- The variable `delta` is a measure that summarizes rib spacing.

```
data <- data.frame(X1 = runif(10),
                   Y1 = runif(10),
                   X2 = runif(10),
                   Y2 = runif(10),
                   X3 = runif(10),
                   Y3 = runif(10),
                   X4 = runif(10),
                   Y4 = runif(10),
                   X5 = runif(10),
                   Y5 = runif(10),
                   X6 = runif(10),
                   Y6 = runif(10),
                   X7 = runif(10),
                   Y7 = c(NA,runif(9)),
                   X8 = c(NA,runif(9)),
                   Y8 = c(NA,NA,runif(8)),
                   X9 = c(NA,NA,runif(8)),
                   Y9 = c(NA,NA,NA,runif(7)),
                   X10 = c(NA,NA,NA,runif(7)),
                   Y10 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(6)),
                   X11 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(6)),
                   Y11 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(5)),
                   X12 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(5)),
                   Y12 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(5)),
                   X13 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(5)),
                   Y13 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   X14 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   Y14 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   X15 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   Y15 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   X16 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   Y16 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   X17 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   Y17 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)),
                   X18 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)),
                   Y18 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)),
                   X19 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)),
                   Y19 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)),
                   X20 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)))

row.names(data) <- LETTERS[1:10]

# Creating the variable n.ribs
data$n.ribs <- rowSums(!is.na(data[,seq(from = 1, to = 39, by = 2)]))

# Creating the variable total.length
data$total.length <- rowSums(data[,1:39], na.rm = TRUE)

# Creating the variable delta
subset.data <- data[,1:39]
last.X.value <- subset.data[cbind(seq_len(nrow(data[,1:39])), max.col(!is.na(data[,1:39]), "last"))]
data$delta <- data$n.ribs / (data$total.length - last.X.value)

# See the dataset
data
```

I'd like to calculate `delta` for parts of the ribcage with approximately equal numbers of ribs. For example, one could split the lizards' ribcage into three sections with approximately the same number of ribs, and then calculate `delta` for the first, second and final third of the ribcage. I just don't have enough proficiency in R language to do this operation. Particularly, I don't know how to split the variable number of ribs into *N* parts of approximately equal length.

Could someone please demonstrate how to create three new variables named `delta.1/3`, `delta.2/3` and `delta.3/3` in the above dataframe? To calculate `delta` for each section, please use the following formula: number of ribs in the section divided by the total length of the section minus the length of the section's last rib.

Some code I've been trying to use and that might be helpful in the answer.

Illustrating the desired operation with lizard B only

```
# Creating a vector containing all non-NA values of lizard B
x <- as.vector(data[2,1:rowSums(!is.na(data[2,1:39]))])
    
# How many values are there for lizard B?
n.values <- rowSums(!is.na(data[2,1:39]))
    
# If divided into 3 sections, how many values will there be in each section?
k <- as.numeric(n.values/3)
    
# Splitting the vector containing all measurement values into 3 chunks
# It's necessary to add some extra code here so that every chunk begins and ends with an X*n* value. For example, the second chunck here begins with variable `Y3`. It should begin with `X4`, and the `Y3` value could be excluded. There's no problem if chunks are of slightly different sizes, but they cannot begin with a Y*n* value.
split.x <- split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/k))
    
# Calculating delta for the first chunk    
chunk1 <- as.data.frame(split.x[[1]])

n.ribs.chunk1 <- length(chunk1[grep("^[X]", names(chunk1), value = TRUE)])

total.length.chunk1 <- sum(chunk1)

last.X.value.chunk1 <- chunk1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(chunk1)), max.col(!is.na(chunk1), "last"))]

delta.chunk1 <- n.ribs.chunk1 / (total.length.chunk1 - last.X.value.chunk1)
```

The above code illustrates the operation with the first chunk of one row. I pointed out problems that need to be resolved before it's possible to apply the above code both for the other two chunks of that row and for all other rows. Loops with `for` might be useful for applying this operation in the entire dataset when we have a code that works for an entire row.

For the other rows, when division into 3 chunks results in non-integer values, it's necessary to require that the first value be rounded up to the next integer while the two other values are rounded down to the next integer. For example, for lizard A: 13 measurements divided into 3 chunks = 4.33. When rounded, the chunks must have 5, 4 and 4 measures. The following code may be useful for this:

```
# How many measures are there for each lizard?
n.measures <- rowSums(!is.na(data[,1:39]))

# Rounded up
ceiling(n.measures/3)

# Rounded down
floor(n.measures/3)
```

Because rows will be split differently, it may be necessary to create a vector for each row and then divide each vector into three vectors using the number obtained above. Then, one could calculate delta for each of these vectors and write the values as new variables in the original dataframe.

Comment: Maybe [Splitting a data frame into equal parts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37145863/10488504) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the `tidyverse` packages, here is one possible solution. Three steps here: 1) tidy your data structure, 2) add the rib grouping variable, 3) summarize the data to get `delta` for each group.

Tidy the data, one observation (rib) per row. Note this example is subset to only lizard B.

```
library(tidyverse)

data_tidy <- data %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = 'lizard_id') %>%
  pivot_longer(X1:X20, 
               names_to = c('var', 'rib_num'), 
               names_pattern = '(.)(.*)') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value) %>%
  rename(rib_length = X, gap_length = Y) 

data_tidy_B <- data_tidy %>%
  filter(lizard_id == 'B',
         !is.na(rib_length))

#------
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  lizard_id n.ribs total.length delta rib_num rib_length gap_length
  <chr>      <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>
1 B              8         5.10  1.76 1           0.169      0.103 
2 B              8         5.10  1.76 2           0.476      0.0265
3 B              8         5.10  1.76 3           0.0251     0.439 
4 B              8         5.10  1.76 4           0.742      0.456 
5 B              8         5.10  1.76 5           0.966      0.178 
6 B              8         5.10  1.76 6           0.498      0.0985
7 B              8         5.10  1.76 7           0.143      0.218 
8 B              8         5.10  1.76 8           0.565     NA
```

Add grouping variable so you know which third of the dataset (ribcage) each rib is in. The `cut` function is the key here.

```
data_third <- data_tidy_B %>%
  mutate(rib_third = as.numeric(rib_num)/n.ribs,
         rib_position = cut(rib_third, 
                            c(0, .33, .66, 1),
                            c('first third', 'second third', 'final third')))  

#----
# A tibble: 8 x 9
  lizard_id n.ribs total.length delta rib_num rib_length gap_length rib_third rib_position
  <chr>      <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>       
1 B              8         6.43  1.25 1          0.642       0.709      0.125 first third 
2 B              8         6.43  1.25 2          0.582       0.0518     0.25  first third 
3 B              8         6.43  1.25 3          0.0257      0.852      0.375 second third
4 B              8         6.43  1.25 4          0.0771      0.0241     0.5   second third
5 B              8         6.43  1.25 5          0.853       0.886      0.625 second third
6 B              8         6.43  1.25 6          0.00693     0.910      0.75  final third 
7 B              8         6.43  1.25 7          0.584       0.218      0.875 final third 
8 B              8         6.43  1.25 8          0.00621    NA          1     final third
```

Finally calculate `delta` for each third of the data

```
data_third%>%
  group_by(lizard_id, rib_position) %>%
  summarize(n_ribs_group = n(),
            group_length = sum(rib_length, gap_length, na.rm = TRUE),
            last_rib_length = rib_length[rib_num == max(rib_num)],
            delta = n_ribs_group/(group_length - last_rib_length))

#----
  lizard_id rib_position n_ribs_group group_length last_rib_length delta
  <chr>     <fct>               <int>        <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>
1 B         first third             2         1.98         0.582    1.43
2 B         second third            3         2.72         0.853    1.61
3 B         final third             3         1.72         0.00621  1.75
```

---

In the example above I created `data` with `set.seed` so the numbers are reproducible

```
set.seed(415)

data <- data.frame(X1 = runif(10),
                   Y1 = runif(10),
                   X2 = runif(10),
                   Y2 = runif(10),
                   X3 = runif(10),
                   Y3 = runif(10),
                   X4 = runif(10),
                   Y4 = runif(10),
                   X5 = runif(10),
                   Y5 = runif(10),
                   X6 = runif(10),
                   Y6 = runif(10),
                   X7 = runif(10),
                   Y7 = c(NA,runif(9)),
                   X8 = c(NA,runif(9)),
                   Y8 = c(NA,NA,runif(8)),
                   X9 = c(NA,NA,runif(8)),
                   Y9 = c(NA,NA,NA,runif(7)),
                   X10 = c(NA,NA,NA,runif(7)),
                   Y10 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(6)),
                   X11 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(6)),
                   Y11 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(5)),
                   X12 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(5)),
                   Y12 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(5)),
                   X13 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(5)),
                   Y13 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   X14 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   Y14 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   X15 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   Y15 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   X16 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   Y16 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   X17 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(4)),
                   Y17 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)),
                   X18 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)),
                   Y18 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)),
                   X19 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)),
                   Y19 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)),
                   X20 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(2)))

row.names(data) <- LETTERS[1:10]

# Creating the variable n.ribs
data$n.ribs <- rowSums(!is.na(data[,seq(from = 1, to = 39, by = 2)]))

# Creating the variable total.length
data$total.length <- rowSums(data[,1:39], na.rm = TRUE)

# Creating the variable delta
subset.data <- data[,1:39]
last.X.value <- subset.data[cbind(seq_len(nrow(data[,1:39])), max.col(!is.na(data[,1:39]), "last"))]
data$delta <- data$n.ribs / (data$total.length - last.X.value)

# See the dataset
data
```

---

Edit: for all individuals

```
library(tidyverse)

data_tidy <- data %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = 'lizard_id') %>%
  pivot_longer(X1:X20, 
               names_to = c('var', 'rib_num'), 
               names_pattern = '(.)(.*)') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value) %>%
  rename(rib_length = X, gap_length = Y) 



data_third <- data_tidy %>%
  filter(!is.na(rib_length)) %>%
  mutate(rib_third = as.numeric(rib_num)/n.ribs,
         rib_position = cut(rib_third, 
                            c(0, .33, .66, 1),
                            c('first third', 'second third', 'final third')))


data_third%>%
  group_by(lizard_id, rib_position) %>%
  summarize(n_ribs_group = n(),
            group_length = sum(rib_length, gap_length, na.rm = TRUE),
            last_rib_length = rib_length[rib_num == max(rib_num)],
            delta = n_ribs_group/(group_length - last_rib_length))


#----
   lizard_id rib_position n_ribs_group group_length last_rib_length delta
   <chr>     <fct>               <int>        <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A         first third             2        2.05          0.0243  0.985
 2 A         second third            2        2.34          0.757   1.26 
 3 A         final third             3        2.50          0.465   1.48 
 4 B         first third             2        1.98          0.582   1.43 
 5 B         second third            3        2.72          0.853   1.61 
 6 B         final third             3        1.72          0.00621 1.75 
 7 C         first third             2        0.757         0.362   5.05 
 8 C         second third            3        2.90          0.558   1.28 
 9 C         final third             4        4.00          0.925   1.30 
10 D         first third             3        3.61          0.254   0.894
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: many thanks for your response! This works for lizard B, but I don't understand the `tidyverse` syntax and I'll have to apply this to larger, more complex datasets, preferably using base R.